# Assign variables inside for loops

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am trying a small code which is

```
for(( i =0;i<2;i++ )); do p$i=\"pra$i\"; done
```

expected output is: 
Variable must be assigned

```
p0="pra0"
p1="pra1"
```

But bash is taking that as command and am getting output as

```
p0="pra0": command not found
p1="pra1": command not found
```

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing about this problem that's specific to `for` loops; it's just a typical indirect-assignment effort. The most common problem folks have with assignments inside loops is when they're piping to the loop (which creates a subshell), causing the things they set to disappear when the loop exits, but that's not the situation here.

Comment: For folks who *are* having that problem, by the way, the appropriate reference is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval` to have the value evaluated and stored as you want:

```
$ for(( i =0;i<2;i++ )); do eval p$i=\"pra$i\"; done
$ echo $p1
pra1
```

---

Or better with `declare` ([thanks chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036966/assign-variables-inside-for-loops/22037058?noredirect=1#comment33422400_22037058) as always!):

```
$ for(( i =0;i<2;i++ )); do declare "p$i=pra$i"; done
$ echo $p1
pra1
```

Comment: Nice to read that, it is a bit tricky the first time :) Note you can mark the answer as accepted if you want.

Comment: Thanks once again ..:)

Comment: Use `declare` instead of `eval` here: `declare "p$i=pra$i"`. Practically speaking, there's not much difference, since we know `$i` is a simple integer, but "right tool for right job" and all.

Comment: Thank you @chepner , I am every day learning new things of bash from you :) Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (( i =0;i<2;i++ )); do
  printf -v "p$i" '%s' "pra$i"
done
```